# iOS Saving Data Best Practice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently, my iOS app calls an API upon launch and the data is subsequently saved to Core Data. Then I unload the Core Data objects (i.e. NSManagedObject) into arrays which I query for particular values, using the NSManagedObject.valueForKey method. When I move along views, I pass important identifying data like user_id from the Core Data cache using prepareForSegue as well as the arrays with the unloaded NSManagedObjects. Since whenever I update the cache, I both save to Core Data and append the new NSManagedObject to my arrays, couldn't I also pass these arrays to the views I need? I don't currently dismiss the original launch page so the arrays persist. Moreover, if I were to update the cache on another page, I would append to the arrays, save to the Core Data cache, and prepareForSegue to overwrite the arrays on main page and wherever else.

This brings forth my critical question. Provided I can accomplish this sort of data persistence using prepareForSegue, is there really a need to have a Core Data cache whereby I'm saving to disk? It seems like I can just call my API from the main page, then save the data to arrays, dictionaries, or a combination of both, and just persist the data via prepareForSegue.

Comment: for sure you can jus persist the data in an array/dictionary, but if that data is every changed/updated or you lose the value of the array/dictionary by switching views, you would need to retrieve the correct array/dictionary from Core Data... if it ever changes before you update to core data then you would be getting the wrong array/dictionary when you retrieve it

Comment: Consider creating a "shared instance" object that is responsible for providing common data to the rest of the application and updating that data when told to.  It can persist the data using whatever mechanism seems right without the rest of the app knowing or caring.  Instead of having to juggle data as part of your segues, view controllers simply ask for what they need when they need it.

Comment: How large is the data that you're passing around? A good reason to stay with core data is if you have too many items to fit into memory at once. Core data makes working with large data sets more practical.